# in java apache.commons.io,how to avoid to read the old log messages

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

i am using the java Tail-listener API to do the tailf function(in Linux).ie,whenever log messages are updated in log file, this API will print the messages.

My code is given below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        File pcounter_log = new File("\vat\temp\test.log");

        try {
            TailerListener listener = new PCTailListener();
            Tailer tailer = new Tailer(pcounter_log, listener, 5000, true);

            Thread thread = new Thread(tailer);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

public class PCTailListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    public void handle(String line) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Initially its working fine.After some time,its reading the old log messages (log messages which are generated at the time of this application gets started). also its reading new log messages too. how to avoid to read the already monitored log messages.How to do this

Comment: I think this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921394/in-java-taillistener-how-to-avoid-duplicate-log-messages, there were some comments posted there already ?