# log4j reduction of repeated messages

Tags: java, log4j

rsyslog has an option, [$RepeatedMsgReduction](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html) tha can be used to reduce the number of log messages in a system. This option groups the same messages, printing the message in the record and then a line with the number of times it has been repeated.

Is it possible to do the same thing with log4j?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132193/log4j-standard-way-to-prevent-repetitive-log-messages

Comment: I was reading now the link that you have paste.  But I was hopeful that that option would have been added to log4j