# Duplicate Messages are getting printed in error.log file. how we can avoid them?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, error-logging

I was trying to replicate the issue in my application, My app continuously logs a lot of DB connection error messages in error.log file, when DB is having some connection issues and it results in server disk full.
How can stop logger to stop reporting duplicate error messages in the error.log file.
Dummy error.log file msgs :

```
10:34:00.577 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:34:00.580 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:34:00.581 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:43:25.736 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:43:25.743 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:43:25.744 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:43:46.320 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Clicked
02:31:44.299 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
02:31:44.302 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
02:31:44.303 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:10:58.422 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Clicked
10:11:11.407 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:11:11.412 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:11:11.413 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:11:39.879 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:11:39.883 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:11:39.883 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:12:00.097 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
10:12:00.100 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:12:00.100 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
10:12:00.118 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
10:12:00.118 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
10:12:00.118 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:38:56.027 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:38:56.055 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:38:56.056 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:38:56.056 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:38:56.056 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:38:56.056 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:39:23.624 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:39:23.640 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:39:23.640 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:39:23.640 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:39:23.640 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:39:23.641 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:39:33.453 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:39:33.467 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:39:33.467 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:39:33.467 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:39:33.467 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:39:33.467 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:45:55.493 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:45:55.512 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:45:55.512 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:45:55.512 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:45:55.512 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:45:55.512 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:46:19.007 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:46:19.017 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:46:19.017 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:46:19.017 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
12:46:19.017 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
12:46:19.017 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
15:02:55.896 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
15:02:55.911 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
15:02:55.911 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
15:02:55.911 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
15:02:55.911 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - DB Crashed
15:02:55.911 [main] FATAL java.lang.Class -  Crashed
```

Please can anyone help to stop these duplicate lines to get printed through logger?

Comment: why would it only be printed once? If that code runs 50 times, and each time there is a problem ... You could of course make sure your DB doesn't crash

Comment: @Stultuske We have resolved DB Issue but whenever this type of issue appears, the app will print millions of lines error logs per sec. which will results in server disk full. 
we want to avoid server disk full.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found the following 2 questions to be relevant: [9132193](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132193/log4j-standard-way-to-prevent-repetitive-log-messages) - [8359839](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359839/how-to-log-repeated-warnings-only-once). I haven't tried them myself, but [Filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html#Filter) might also help in situations like this I think (if you keep some state in your interface implementation).